# How can I remove this line of the app's name from my Flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter

In my Flutter app, somehow a line with the name of the app just appeared, and dunno why. How can I remove it? [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMS1d.png) (I'm using VS Code, with Android Studio's Emulator)

I tried to do something with the appbar, but that's not the problem. This line appear in every screen, even if there is no appbar at all.
edit.: I posted the manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<application
    android:label="appname"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2"/>
</application>
```

Comment: It’s likely due to an altered AndroidManifest.xml or an AppBar widget. Can you post both AndroidManifest file and the widget code of the problematic screen?

Comment: if you are using Text widget then use TextOverflow.ellipsis in that widget, otherwise make small size of that particular widget. still not resolved then send snapshot of that code.

Comment: Alright, I uploaded the manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after like 30mins of talking with BingAI, I found the error; so I just had to overwrite the theme to this, and also add a label.

```
 android:label=""
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```